# C++ string char** translation

Tags: c++, string, char, calloc

How can I make an array of n strings using char**?

```
char** lit;
*lit = (char*)calloc(this->nr_param, sizeof(char*));
for(int i = 0; i < this->nr_param; i++)
      lit[i] = (char*) calloc(this->nr_param, sizeof(char));
```

Is this the way?
If so, how can i access elements? Lets say my array will contain the following elements:
aaab, abba, baab;

I want this structure:

```
lit[0] = "aaab";
lit[1] = "abba";
lit[2] = "baab";
```

It's ok how I declared them?

Comment: Why? Surely you should use `vector<string>`? And as for the code in the Q, the first calloc needs `sizeof(char*)` rather than `sizeof(char)` and the second calloc needs to allocate enough for the string and will bear no relation to `nr_param`.

Comment: Why do you need strings? there is no c++ string in your code?

Comment: I don't want to use vector<string> because I will extensively use arrays functions like lit[0][i], i being the char from position i

Comment: @Dementor what makes you think that you can't do that with `vector<string>`?

Comment: Then I shall be using vector<string>* lit = new vector<string>(); for(i < lit.size) for(j < strlen(lit[i])) dosth with lit[i][j]?

Comment: @Dementor: That's a classic case of where you've been learning C++ the wrong way round. The `vector<string>` is by far the superior solution and behaves exactly as you need, but for some reason you deluded yourself into thinking that pointers are needed in C++ (which most times they're not).

Comment: @Dementor: No no no, never use `new`. Just `std::vector<std::string> lit;`, and done. Forget about pointers and `new`, seriously. Those are very advanced, niche topics that you should not need until such a time where you know confidently that you need them.

Comment: @Dementor And don't use `strlen` either. Use `string::length()`. You need to unlearn all these unsafe C-isms and start using C++.

Comment: @Dementor C++ is a different beast than C. Please get a book on boost or stl. It will save a lot of sleepless nights and heart ache (then again I do not know your partner!)

Comment: And even if it were C, there still would be some glaring errors in the OP's code. Do we need to address this now? Do we need to teach the OP about C?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
// allocate memory for n char pointers dynamically.
char ** lit = static_cast<char**>(::operator new(n * sizeof(char*)));

for (unsigned int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
{
    lit[i] = static_cast<char*>(::operator new(length_of_string_i)); // #1
    // populate lit[i] with data
}
```

You need some method of determining the length of the `i`th string, which you need to paste appropriately in the line marked #1. Note that `sizeof(char) == 1`, so you don't need to multiply anything in the inner allocation.
(You can use `std::malloc` instead of `::operator new` if you prefer, but then you have to `#include <cstdlib>`.) Don't forget to clean up when you're done!

This is of course only the literal translation of what you asked for. In C++, you would usually prefer *object creation* over raw *memory allocation*, which looks like this:

```
// construct n char pointers dynamically
char ** lit = new char*[n];

for (unsigned int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
{
    lit[i] = new char[length_of_string_i];
    // populate lit[i] with data
}
```

But you should seriously never use array-new. It's not a good concept, and rarely good C++.

So, you shouldn't be doing this at all, and instead you should use:

```
std::vector<std::string> lit(n);
```

Comment: Worth noting that `length_of_string_i` needs to allow space for the zero-terminator

Comment: Can you explain why you write `new(n * sizeof(char*))` instead of `new char*[n]`?

Comment: @MrLister: I didn't write that. I wrote `::operator new(n * sizeof(char*))`, just to correspond to what the OP (presumably misguidedly) asked for. `new char*[n]` does a different thing, at least conceptually.

Comment: @KerrekSB But your code (copied and pasted unchanged) doesn't compile under g++ 4.6.1.

Comment: @MrLister: Ah, yes, you need a cast... this is altogether ugly and terrible, I agree.

Answer (score 2):

You can use c++ vector and strings in a similar way:

```
  #include <vector>
  #include <string>
  #include <iostream>
  int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> lit;
    lit.push_back("aaab");
    lit.push_back("aab");
    lit.push_back("aabb");
    lit[0][0] = 'z';
    std::cout << lit[0] << std::endl;
  }
```